# UIInterfaceOrientation always return Portrait in AppDelegate iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, splash-screen, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to show the Splash Screen in iPad application. Before that i want to get the current device orientation Landscape or Portrait mode. I have used,

```
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation= [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)  
    {       
        splachview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768)];
        splachview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Landscape.png"];

        splachview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        splachview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
        [self.window addSubview:splachview];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {
        splachview=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
        splachview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-Portrait.png"];

        splachview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        splachview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeTop;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
        [self.window addSubview:splachview];
    }
```

in `Appdelegate.m` . The UIInterface orienation always detecting in Portrait mode only. I launched the app in Landscape mode but, the control always detecting Portrait mode only. How can i get the current orientation in `AppDelegate.m`? Please help me to find the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that on the `AppDelegate`, but rather on a `UIViewController`. In a `UIViewController` you can correctly know in what position the device is, by [using the appropriate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (**Configuring the View Rotation Settings** section) that the class gives you.

Comment: Mr.Jack Boy thanks for your answer. Before this code i kept the splash screen code in UIViewController only. By your way When i rotate the app the splash screen does not change its orientation. That is why i wrote the code in AppDelegate. And also in AppDelegate i wrote the code for getting LogInToken. I need to show the splash screen until i get the loginToken. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Well sure, are you allowing the screen to rotate? on the: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

Comment: Mr.Jack Boy i feel confident to solve my problem after your answer. Ya am following - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation method in UIViewController. Another one problem is Am calling [viewcontrollerobj showSplash]; method in AppDelegate to show Splash screen. Then i am continuing the XMLParser in AppDelegate. In didEndParsing Delegate i tried to hide the splash screen by using [viewcontrollerobj hideSplash]; but, when the control reach this method the app getting crash. How can i solve this? Hope you understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: Humm, can you show me the error? Also, you should avoid doing that kind of operations in the AppDelegate.. You could do the Parsing on a class specifically design for that, and use your UIViewController to receive the response once the parse is complete.

Comment: Now i solved the app crashing problem. Still am struggling to show the splash screen in Default-Landscape.png in Portrait mode. When i launch the app in Landscape mode the Splash Screen in Portrait mode only. Please help me. I followed your thought. I removed the code from AppDelegate and wrote the SplashScreen code in UIViewController. Thanks. I want your help.

Comment: Are you able to tell me if the application is able to rotate in some way?

Comment: Ya iPad app should rotate in both Landscape and Portrait. The Splash Screen only not supporting for orientation changes. Other than entire app is working fine and change it's orientation very fine. I have specified the frame size of the splashView(UIImageView) in -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOr‌​ientation: still the orientation does not change itself. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't do that there... That method is used to say if you allow the screen to rotate for a given UIInterfaceOrientation... You should do the rotations here: -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6614/discussion-between-gopinath-and-jacky-boy)

Comment: Ya i have tried your thought. But, still the issue is happening. Can you please help me by any other way? Thanks and looking forward your help. I have tried my level best and spent this whole day for this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please send me your mail id or something to receive my sample project? Thanks.

Comment: I sent the code to your mail id. Please check the code and let me know the correction. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After read your code, seems like what you want is to show a static image when app startup. There is way to do that without any code.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12

If you want to show any dynamic content as "splash", you may need to process it in a UIViewController.

For get current device orientation, you can read property: [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation. Just for your reference.

Comment: Mr.Hail Zhang thanks for your answer. Before this code i kept the splash screen code in UIViewController only. By your way When i rotate the app the splash screen does not change its orientation. That is why i wrote the code in AppDelegate. And also in AppDelegate i wrote the code for getting LogInToken. I need to show the splash screen until i get the loginToken. Can you please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, this maybe comes toooooo later :-)  As I know, there is one probably issue is that the rootViewController.view will not rotate itself. Which means, you need to create a container view as full size as rootViewController.view, and make it autorotate mark as full width and full height, then, you will be able to get auto rotate when your device orientation changes.