# Is there anyway to get the PayPal web view to rotate for landscape mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, paypal

i am currently developing an ios app that uses PayPal's Mobile Payment Library to facilitate payment of goods.The Problem is that Paypal generates a web view that set to portrait -Upright mode. This is to my knowledge is generated inside the payPal library and i can't see anyway to acces it . Is there anyway to make te web view rotate in landscape mode.After some extensive searching i found that most everyone are just using the portait mode ,is there anyway to make it rotate to landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually there is a way to manually rotate the checkbox view of paypal in iOS. This view is an instance of PayPalViewClass. Just add a method to look through all the views and all the subviews to find the instanse of this class. Once you've found the view you was looking for just apply setTransform method to it.
The method should look like like this:

```
-(void)cicle:(UIView *)aView {
    for (UIView *_v in [aView subviews]) {
        if ([_v isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"PayPalViewClass") class]]) {
            [aView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];
        }
        [self cicle:_v];
    }
}
```

It should be called in your payWithPayPal method.
I hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.
Since PayPal is adding its view to the key window and not the root view controller, then it ignores the device orientation.

There are many questions here that explain the landscape orientation issue, when adding a subview directly to a window, for example:
[UIInterfaceOrientation always return Portrait in AppDelegate iPad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816252/uiinterfaceorientation-always-return-portrait-in-appdelegate-ipad)

I am trying to catch PayPal UIView and rotate it manually, but not figured out if it is possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

For Paypal library v1.6.0, the `PayPalViewClass` is in view hierarchy of application's main `window`.

1. You just need to call method provided by @alex and pass your app's delegate window.
2. To get the window `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]` is enough.
3. Put the call after you call `-advancedCheckoutWithPayment:` or `-checkoutWithPayment:`.

If you allow all orientations, you will need to transform the `PayPalViewClass` accordingly to device orientation.